# Re-executing JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, loading

I asked this sort of question before ( [Application fails to dynamically _re_load JavaScript files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309694/application-fails-to-dynamically-reload-javascript-files) ) but I couldn't quite resolve the problem (if it has any solution), so I will put this in another fashion, a simpler one:

Can one unload a file from the browser's memory for posterior reloading?
(Removing the  tag is not enough apparently.)

Or more relevant, if a reinsert the  tag after removing it, is that code rerun (apparently not)?

How can accomplish the latter?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate a random number and then attach it to the end of the filename like this: `.../script.js?r=0.25300762383267283`. Then the browser would think it's a new file and not reference it from the cache.

Comment: I think that helped somehow. Noticed something though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704979/re-insertion-of-script-tags
The code seems to be rerun nevertheless, so mission accomplished and I guess some of the problems I had were not because of this but DOM related issues which I will check out now. Thanks Alexsander.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to unload a script file.
As to the re-run issue, you could try giving each instance you call a JS file a varying GET parameter (e.g. the current timestamp). That might / should cause the browser to re-execute the file.

What are you trying to achieve? There may be smarter ways than re-loading a script file.

Comment: The given link shows a given use case for what I am trying to do :)

Comment: ?? I don't understand. Does that help you or not? And why do you open a 2nd identical question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704979/re-insertion-of-script-tags

Comment: @Pekka Gaiser: How are they duplicated? They are related, but not the same question.

Comment: @Pekka Gaiser: Thanks :) And your idea is pretty much the same as Alexsander Akers's I might add, so thanks for that too.